# Rank an unsorted list of integers in an array in C

Tags: arrays, c

I'm doing an assignment where I have an array of integers in an unsorted form and my task is to rank each integer according to its value where the largest value will get 1st rank and the smallest values will get *n*-rank (in an array of 20 integers the lowest value will have rank 20). I cannot use 2D arrays as we haven't learned them yet. So I can only use <stdio.h> library. I'm struggling to write an algorithm that will solve the problem.

I'm not asking for a solution here so please don't post a code but rather some hints on how to build the algorithm or how to think here. Thank you in advance for any ideas and suggestions!

Comment: Can you sort the array? Can you sort it in place? Is there an efficiency requirement for the problem? Could you use a second array to hold the ranking (because I'm not sure why you come up with a 2D array mention in the first place; a second array of the same size would just work fine)? What happens with identical values, in which case ranks may be skipped, or the lowest ranks will not be there?

Comment: hmmm lots of questions: What are you supposed to do with the rank? Print it, store it or ... Are you allowed to change the order of elements in the array, e.g. sort the array?

Comment: You might want to check this out: [Sorting Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm). Go through the list of popular sorting algorithms given there and read them individually...

Comment: I have to print it later but I am not worried about the printing part. Once I find rank and replace value with ranks then I can print each value. But I'm firstly concerned with the algorithm of ranking :-). I'll veck out sorting algorithms, thank you!

Comment: You were right, I had to store the ranks in anther array. I'm posting the solution down below:

Answer (score 0):

Start by setting the rank to zero. To find the rank of th i'th element you can iterate all element of the array. If an element is greater than the i'th element, increment the rank. If an element is equal to the i'th element, increment rank if-and-only-if that element is before the i'th element.

Here is some pseudo code to find the rank of the i'th element

```
* i = "index of element to rank"
* j = 0
* rank = 0
* while j < array-size do:
      * if array[j] > array[i] do: rank = rank + 1
      * if array[j] == array[i] and j < i do: rank = rank + 1
      * j = j + 1
* print rank
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is part of the code with 2 x for loops where I go through an array of results and compare each result with all other results and then calculate how many values are less than or equal to the value. I do this for each value. Then I record number of points for each value in another array and the highest points go the lowest value. Thank you everybody for your inputs! Apologies I couldn't post complete question as it would have been bad praxis.

```
> for(l=0; l<no_students; l++){
>         points=0;
>         for(i=0; i<no_students; i++){
>             if(array[l]<=array[i]){
>                 points++;
>             }
>             rank[l]=points;
>         }
>                     j++;
>     }
```

Comment: Depending on the amount of data and how often you do it, this might be inefficient. In general you'll want to work with sorted data. And it would seem that a single call to `qsort` would have solved this as well.

Comment: I agree with you but I'm just a beginner and still learning C, so in my course we get assignments to test and practice our knowledge with whatever we learned. I am aware that code efficiency is very important for the program execution, time, cpu usage and I hope to be able to improve over time. In this exercise we had 3 values to work with :-)